# Differential on $E_2$-page in LHS spectral sequence

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

I have the following questions. Let
$$
0\to A\to G\to Q\to 1
$$
be a central group extension. Also let $id$ be the cohomology class in $H^1(A,A)$ corresponding to the identity homomorphism ($A$ is always treated below as a trivial module).

Now consider the cohomological Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence associated to this extension with coefficients in $A$. Then:

1. Assuming that $A=\mathbb{Z}/p$, is it true that $d_2(id)\in H^2(Q,A)$ is equal to $\beta$, the cohomology class of this extension (as defined in Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra*, section 6.6)?
2. If the first claim is true, would it still be true for all abelian groups $A$? Or at least finitely generated ones?

Thanks!

EDIT: As per request, I am adding some context. I know that the needed differential is the transgression. Now if I think about LHS spectral sequence as the spectral sequence associated to the fibration
$$
NA\to NG\to NQ,
$$
then I have the diagram (see McCleary's *Introduction to Spectral Sequences*, Section 6.2):
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
0@>>>H^2(NQ,\ast;A)@>>>H^1(NQ,A)@>>>0\\
@VVV @V p_0^\ast VV @VpVV @.\\
H^1(NA,A)@>d>> H^2(NG,NA;A)@>>> H^2(NG,A).
\end{CD}
Here rows are exact and the maps $p_0^\ast$ and $p^\ast$ are induced from the map of pairs $(NG, NA)\to (NQ,\ast)$. Now in order to know that $d_2(id)=\beta$, using the transgression I need to know that $p_0^\ast(\beta)=d(id)$. And this is what I cannot see, given the usual definition of $\beta$: I am choosing set theoretic section $\eta\colon Q\to G$ such that $\eta(1)=1$, and I define
$$
\beta(g,h)=\eta(g)\eta(h)\eta(gh)^{-1}.
$$
If someone knows a reference, a reference would do for me. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Ok, while I think that downvote+close vote is too harsh on a clearly stated question, I admit lack of context here. Let me correct it up to tomorrow.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly fine pair of questions. I see no reason to close.

Comment: @Shaun Context added, as per request. However, I do not agree with your second comment - asking these questions as two separate posts would not make sense, as it is really one question, divided into two parts.